# "Помилка". На який склад робити наголос?

Tags: наголос

На який склад правильно зробити наголос у слові ***[помилка](http://sum.in.ua/s/pomylka)***? 
Згідно зі статтею [«Норми наголошування»](http://www.interklasa.pl/portal/dokumenty/ridna_mowa_uk/index.php?page=rm35_04) Світлани Лахвич у № 35 журналу «Рідна мова»:

> В українській мові є правила акцентуації, які поширюються на певні групи слів: <…> відіменникові та віддієслівні іменники з префіксами *ви-*, *від-*, *за-*, *на-*, *над-*, *об-*, *пере-*, *під-*, *по-*, *при-*, *про-*, *роз-*, мають наголос здебільшого на префіксах (*за́хід*, *ро́зстріл*, *за́тишок*, *пере́біг*, *при́повідка* тощо); винятки *розгро́м*, *зачи́н*, *набі́р*

Тобто начебто наголос у слові *помилка* має падати на перший склад. Але з іншого:

> До особливостей наголошування слів української мови належать: <…> подвійне наголошування слів (*за́вжди́*, *по́ми́лка*)

Як розрізнити ці два варіанти наголосів?

Comment: @Sasha так, "Склад" не "наголос".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Відразу коротка відповідь, а потім докази.

Відповідь:

Хоч за найновішим повним словником української мови у 11 томах наголос і є подвійний (тобто, не можна вказувати людям, що вони припустилися помилки, якщо вони наголошують це слово на другий склад), але стаття, яку ви знайшли, абсолютно відповідає дійсності до початку зближення мов. Отже, цілком лоґічно наголошувати це слово саме за тим правилом, на яке ви послалися, на перший склад: по́милка.

Докази:

[Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on):

> по́милка лиш на о́ко така́.
>
> по́милка на сло́ві,
>
> по́милка на (в) реча́х.

[Словарь української мови 1909р. (Б. Грінченко)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=12&highlight=on):

> У по́милку.

[Російсько-український словник технічної термінології 1928р. (І. Шелудько, Т. Садовський)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=4&highlight=on):

> по́милка;

[Словник українсько-російський 1927р. (А. Ніковський)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=8&highlight=on):

> При́кра по́милка
>
> Нам уклю́нулася по́милка

[Російсько-український словник ділової мови 1930р. (М. Дорошенко, М. Станиславський, В. Страшкевич)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=5&highlight=on):

> по́милка була́ в то́му.
>
> по́милка на вазі́;
>
> по́милка на сло́ві.

[Правописний словник 1929р. (Г. Голоскевич)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=11&highlight=on):

> по́милка, -лки, -лці; -милки, -милок

Обмовлюсь тут, що ТАК, є словники і до 1930-х років, які наголошують це слово на другий склад, але там максимум є подвійний наголос (а частіше або й завжди - різний у різних статтях), і вони менш поважні за словники Єфремова, Грінченка тощо, тому загальної ситуації це не змінює.