# Наголос у множині «помилки»

Tags: наголос

Я читала про можливий подвійний наголос пОмилка і помИлка, але не знайшла однозначної інформації про наголос в множині, особливо, родовий відмінок: пОмилок, помИлок чи помилОк? Підкажіть, будь ласка, як правильно?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Помилка". На який склад робити наголос?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/3228/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%9d%d0%b0-%d1%8f%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81)

Comment: @Daria ваше питання є повною копією [цього питання](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/3228/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%9d%d0%b0-%d1%8f%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81). За правилами платформи SE, це питання-дублікат. Будь ласка, закрийте його і надалі, перш ніж ставити питання, перевірте чи на нього або на подібне вже не відповідали(в такому випадку також можна вважати ваше питання питанням-дублікатом).

Comment: @bytebuster, я спочатку хотів підтримати Вас, але потім подивився уважніше, і зрозумів, що в тому дописі немає ані слова про множину, а Daria, як я розумію, зазначає, що якраз читала той допис, але питає про множину.

Comment: @improbable, те саме.

Comment: @Sasha, я вважаю, що "наголос у слові помилка" — це достатня межа гранульованості запитань на цьому сайті. Якщо ми вважатимемо самостійно-істотним запитання "наголос у слові помилка **у множині**", то що зупинить когось від подальшого поділу і отримання ще 2*7=14 запитань виду "наголос у слові помилка **в однині** у **давальному відмінку**".

Comment: Правильним рішенням є або (1) редагування наявного запитання, щоб покрити усі відмінювання слова "помилка", або (2) редагування цього запитання, щоб воно покривало певне правило — як-то "усі трьохскладові слова, що закінчуються на `-ка`" — авжеж, №2 за умови, що таке правило існує, як-то наявна [низка запитань](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5478/8) щодо `-а / -у` у родовому відмінку іменників II відміни.

Comment: @bytebuster, якщо коротко, то ми не можемо посилати автора запитання туди, не відповіді на його запитання просто немає. Якщо докладніше, то можемо це обговорити в [чаті](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117616/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### «Словники України онлайн» від УМІФ

[«Словники України онлайн» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/), незважаючи на те, що дають подвійний наголос у відмінках однини цього слова, для множини дають **лише один варіант** наголосу:

> | відмінок | однина | множина |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | називний | пО́мИ́лка | **помилкИ́** |
> | родовий | пО́мИ́лки | **помилО́к** |
> | давальний | пО́мИ́лці | **помилкА́м** |
> | знахідний | пО́мИ́лку | **помилкИ́** |
> | орудний | пО́мИ́лкою | **помилкА́ми** |
> | місцевий | на/у пО́мИ́лці | **на/у помилкА́х** |
> | кличний | пО́мИ́лко | **помилкИ́** |

Наголос при числівниках *два*, *три*, *чотири* відповідає наголосу в родовому відмінку однини, а не наголосу в називному відмінку множини (загалом це типово для української мови: *нема козИ́*, *мої кО́зи*, *дві козИ́*), тобто **з  *два*, *три*, *чотири* наголос теж подвійний**.

### Інші погляди

#### Словник Кримського і Єфремова

Російсько-український словник Кримського і Єфремова (1924–1933), якщо це, звісно, не описка й помилка сканування, [дозволяє](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%96+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8&dicts=1&highlight=on) подвійний наголос навіть для множини:

> Оши́бка — по́ми́лка, о́(б)ми́лка, по́хибка, хи́ба. [Ортографі́чні **по́милки́**, по́хибки. По́милка за фальш не йде́ = -ка в фальшь не ставишся].

— але в цьому випадку наголошуються не 1-й і 2-й склад (як в однині), а 1-й і 3-й.

#### Висновки

Якщо хочете точно не помилитись, кажіть *мої помилкИ́*, *моїх помилО́к* тощо. Але деякі словники вважають допустимими *мої пО́милки*, *моїх пО́милок* тощо теж (але не «*мої помИ́лки*», «*моїх помИ́лок*» тощо).